# filter dataframe on index date column (lte)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follow:

```
                                 quantity
2021-07-30 06:51:30.386126+00:00       20
2021-07-30 06:40:34.057085+00:00     2000
2021-07-06 10:12:31.293255+00:00     2000
```

I want to get the sum of 'quantity' before a 'certain date'.
I looked on internet and the solution I found was to filter the dataframe first as:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[None:f"{current_date}"]
```

However when I do this for instance with current_date = datetime.date(2021, 7, 30)
I'm not getting the quantity from 2021-07-06.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you need to sort first on `date`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the slicing. You are currently selecting dates after `current_date` instead of before.

```py
filtered_df = df.loc[f"{current_date}":None]
```